# Grub menu without Ubuntu options that work

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04

Here's my system boot info http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/cDrjxGQjG4/

Today my boot was hanging with some errors.
This is probably related with some automated update on my system, since I did not install or updated any package or app today.

I tried booting an Ubuntu installation using a LiveUSB.
I have run boot-repair, but that made things worse.
The grub menu options are now

[image]

I did not had these EFI options before running boot-repair.
But both ubuntu entries does not work.
The first one go to a black screen and returns to the menu.
The second one shows some UI that I dont understand.

Can someone please help me?
What is the easiest solution to get my system back?

Thanks

Comment: sorry for missing that, I've added it. Thanks K7AAY